# Swapping inputs on CircuiTikz amplifier

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to change the positive and negative inputs of the amplifier, so that the top is the positive one and the bottom the negative one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yscale=-1` to flip top-bottom, `xscale=-1` to flip left-right, and `scale=-1` to flip both directions at the same time.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) node[op amp] {};
  \draw (3,0) node[op amp,yscale=-1] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]